# Does this crystal circuit work?

Tags: oscillator, crystal, transmitter, high-frequency, ham-radio

I need a tiny oscillator circuit for testing an application. Now I haven't much experience in creating oscillators so I would like to use this Collpits-circuit:

[image: fig1]

I only need the carrier wave so I deleted the parts needed for modulation (I hope):

[image: fig2]

So I want to ask, if this is ok and might be oscillate?

Comment: You could have searched for collpits and discovered tons of simpler variants...

Comment: Please disregard my comment; I had a misconfigured network. Images load fine.

Comment: Surely you also need R3 and S1 from the original circuit for it to transmit.

Comment: If they're not your drawings or designs then you need to credit the original author. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) Hit the [edit] link ...

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right.  You just need to add R3 (120 ohm) back, so that you will have the carrier "on" continuously (all the time). You should be able to remove R2 (15k) without causing a noticeable effect.